# Using substrings to count the number of times a word appears

Tags: c

I want to use substrings to count the number of times a specific word has been typed in. I have been playing with my code a little to see if I could make it work but I just don't get it!

My code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

int i=0;

char buf[1026]={'\0'};
char *p="#EOF\n";
char *t;

while (strcmp(buf, p) != 0)
{
    fgets(buf, 1025, stdin);
    t=strtok(buf," , - \n");
    while(t != NULL)
    {
        if(strncmp(t, argv[1], strlen(argv[1])) == 0)
    {
        i++;
    }
    }
}






printf("%d\n", i);

return 0;
}
```

There are no errors, but the value of `i` is always 0. I don't know how to make sure it keeps counting after it finds the word once. I tried `sizeof(t) < j`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: You probably want `strlen` instead of `sizeof`.

Comment: This seems very inefficient to me. Why are you parsing the string into substrings? All you need to do is find your delimiters and count the results. There's no reason to waste cycles modifying the string. Use something like `strpbrk()` to find the next occurrence of one of several characters or write your own help function.

Comment: @JonathanWood but can you count the number of times one word is typed in if for example the same word is 5 times on one line and then an enter is typed in and then the same word is another 3 times there; will it count 8 then?

Comment: Sure, if you write the code correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for more than one instance of the token you need to call strtok multiple times. On subsequent calls pass in NULL as the first argument. See the [man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strtok.3.html)

Also, sizeof(t) is a constant, probably 4 or 8. t is a char pointer, it takes up some amount of bytes. If you're looking to see if strtok returned something you want to compare against NULL. From the man page:

> RETURN VALUE
>
> ```
>   The strtok() and strtok_r() functions return a pointer 
>    to the next token, or  NULL  if there are no more tokens.
> ```

The NULL is what you want to check for to determine that there are no more tokens on that line.

Also note that if a token bridges two reads, you won't get it. For example line 1 ends with " ," and the next ready starts with "- \n"

Comment: I changed the code to the above, is this what you meant or not?

Comment: If you want to look for another bit of delimited text you're going to need to call strtok again. I'm surprised it's not an infinite loop on match as t isn't reassigned in the while loop.

Comment: I really dont have any idea what you mean I'm sorry. Could you maybe give me a slight hint or so?

Comment: you want to call strtok in the inner while loop

Answer (score 0):

```
while(sizeof(t) > j)
```

[`sizeof`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof) tells you the size of a type, so in your case, it's `sizeof(char*)`, which is just the size of a pointer on your platform. Most likely it's always 4 or 8. Replace it with [`strlen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/), which is designed to tell you the size of a string.